# TypeError: jQuery.ajax(...) is undefined

Tags: jquery

Jquery library is correctly loaded in my Drupal installation but why do I get "TypeError: jQuery.ajax(...) is undefined" exception in Firebug for this code:

```
function get(url,results_id,json) {
    var url2 = url + '&' + parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);    

    var target_id = '#' + results_id;
    if (json) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
        }).done(function ( data ) {
            jQuery(target_id).html(data.r);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Could not get data.');
        });        
    } else {
        jQuery.get(url2, function(data) {
            jQuery(target_id).html(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Could not get data.');
        });        
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I've trimmed the code to this and it does not show any error now. Looks like some problem with the done part:

```
function get(url,results_id,json) {
    var url2 = url + '&' + parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);    

    var target_id = '#' + results_id;
    if (json) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
    //  cache:false
        })
        ;        
    } 
}
```

Comment: what version of jquery you using? try $.ajax instead of jquery.ajax

Comment: It is 1.4.4 and if I use $.ajax then it shows in $ is undefined

Comment: how do you include your jquery file? The message tell that you not include your jquery properly, + you should think of using the latest jquery, which is 1.11.1

Comment: @user5858 "*Looks like some problem with the done part*" [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), including [`.then()`, `.done()`, etc.](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), were [introduced with 1.5](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/). You'll have to upgrade jQuery to use them.

Comment: When I replaced done with "success" it worked so it was version problem. Thanks Jonathan.